# Why didn't Siris/Ausar die in the first Infinity Blade itself?

Tags: infinity-blade

In the first IB, the God King stabs siris with the Infinity Blade. Since, he was believed to be a mortal in IB1, its understandable that he died and his bloodline trying to get revenge. But, after IB2, it is revealed that he is, in fact, another Deathless.

It is clearly stated at the end of IB1, that the Infinity Blade has the "ability to prevent immortals like the God King from resurrecting after death"

My question is this:
If Siris aKa Ausar was indeed a Deathless, shouldn't the Infinity Blade have killed him permanently in IB1 itself? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Not really relevant, but still hilarious: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dtgsXt692-o

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about developer and writers intent, which cannot be covered.

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness I don't get how its off-topic. Its a valid question. I can add sources referencing the question and story if you want. I would even accept plausible theories, because this question is just bugging me.

Comment: The part where a question is bugging you doesn't mean it's on or off-topic. @NoneOfYourBusiness I read it as a lore question, and these are on topic. I'm not sure though. It sure looks like it poking at a plothole. I don't know the games, so I'm not doing anything.

Comment: @Arperum being a lore question isn't a free pass against our other standards. Lore questions that are fundamentally speculative/Dev intent based are just as off topic as "why did my favorite item get nerfed."

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz I didn't say that though, I was mostly replying to NOYB that it is not a developer intent question. Based on the comment that "plausible theories will be accepted" it might be way to speculative to be answerable. I don't know. I don't know the games we are talking about, so I'm not going to vote on this either way. Except if I get a very clear argument why I should vote one direction or the other.

Comment: This one seems to pretty darn close to a game of, "Poke the plot hole".  It could very well be that the lore for Infinity Blade doesn't actually answer this question, inherently making it unanswerable.

Comment: @Arperum It is not because I don't like it. If this plot hole is not covered in the game, then there is nothing we can do to answer it besides speculating, But exactly that makes it offtopic and the question goes into a matter of writers/developers intent.

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness *that*'s the part where you need knowledge of the game series for. It's poking at something that looks like a plothole, but could very well be explained in universe, it's also possible that it is not. And at that point, you are right and the question is going into purely speculative areas. But I can't decide on that.

Comment: @Arperum I am not going to retract my close vote if that is what you are shooting at.

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness Not at all! I personally don't *like* the question, but since I have a complete lack of knowledge about it, I refuse to vote in any direction. What others vote is up to them, I can perfectly understand your point of voting to close, just as I also understand people wanting to keep it open.

Comment: First, I don't know whether I poked at a plot hole. Second, its a genuine On-Topic question related to Infinity Blade game series. Third, I am quite sure that you would've found it on topic, IF you knew about the game or had played it. My question simply asks if I missed something, because I haven't seen this question anywhere when I googled for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer on Infinity Blade Forums. Here it is!

The answer lies in the books and on ChAIR's YouTube channel!

The reason he didn't die was because something went wrong when the Worker created the IB, and it had to be "charged" first. It had to be attuned to someone's QIP(Quantum Identity Pattern) by killing them over and over and over again before it would be able to actually permanently kill a Deathless. This is where the IB1 loop comes from; Radriar is actually attuning the blade to Ausar's QIP over many generations by killing him over and over.

Whenever Siris is actually able to defeat God-King Radriar, this is actually the last kill needed to fully charge the Blade. When he takes it down to the dungeons, he permanently kills the Deathless Kings down there with the IB; it's fully charged, then he leaves and the story of IB: Awakening and then IB2 takes place.